# Editing a specific cell based on any change to another specific cell in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

In a Google Sheet, is it possible to automatically edit (i.e. toggle a checkbox or change color) a cell whenever another specific cell in that same row is changed in any way? For example, if I wanted to toggle a checkbox in cell *A1* whenever the value in cell *D1*, *K1*, or *M1* was changed, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible by using Google Apps Script. If you need further help please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  ss = e.source
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  range = e.range //This is the edited range

  if(range.getA1Notation() == "D1") {
    sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('TRUE')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- toggle a checkbox: yes, possible
- change color: also possible

> whenever the value in cell D1, K1, or M1 was changed

depends if by manual change or not

example - if any of those 3 cells become "not empty" the checkbox gets checked:

[image: 0]

then a color change can be done like:

[image: 0]